# Vulnerability with image-credentials-provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, security, binary, amazon-eks

I have eks cluster running in AWS with 15 nodes. I use wiz tool to scan our servers on daily basis. New vulnerabilities popped up it is CVE-2023-39325 with high severity.

The thing is go is not installed on those 15 servers. it is amazon linux2 ec2 machines. red hat. I know go binaries is the part of kubelet to be functional, so removing the files is not an option. Wiz report says

> The library golang.org/x/net version 0.0.0-20220127200216-cd36cc0744dd was detected in Golang binary located at /etc/eks/ecr-credential-provider/ecr-credential-provider and is vulnerable to CVE-2023-39325, which exists in versions < 0.17.0.

but when I proceed to that location theres no such file. my location is following `/etc/eks/image-credential-provider/ecr-credential-provider` and there are two files `config.json` and `ecr-`

I installed go with yum and version is `go1.20.10 linux/amd64` and tried to run `go get -u golang.org/x/net`

```
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'
```

this is the output im getting. And with go install

```
flag provided but not defined: -u
usage: go install [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help install' for details.
```

any tips and help appreciated

```
go get -u golang.org/x/net
go install -u golang.org./x/net
```

Comment: "detected in Golang binary" so this is telling you that an executable, built using Go, utilises a library vulnerable to a denial of service attack (so you don't need to install Go, you need to update the impacted executable/package - not sure why the executable is not where the warning indicates it is).